# What does this GHC.Generic function signature error message mean?

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm learning Haskell. Why can't I change `Person` to type variable `a` in the method signature of `getName`

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module Main where

import GHC.Generics


data Person = Person { id   :: Int
                     , name :: String
                     , age  :: Int }
            deriving (Generic, Show)

p = from $ Person 12 "J" 12

getName :: (Rep Person) x -> String
-- getName :: Generic a => (Rep a) x -> String
----^ Err: Couldn't match type ‘Rep a0’ with ‘Rep a
getName f = concat [ moduleName f
                   , "_"
                   , datatypeName f
                   ]

n = getName p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rep` is an associated type-synonym i.e. the actual type can be anything depending on the implementation of the specific type-class instance. There is no guarantee that `Rep a` for any arbitrary `a` is a type that is compatible with the type required by the function `moduleName`.

`Rep Person` works because the compiler is able to check that the associated type for the type-class instance of `Generic Person` fits the type expected by `moduleName` (which is `Datatype d => t d (f :: * -> *) a`).

Instead of using `Rep a` you can instead use

```
getName :: Datatype d => t d (f :: * -> *) a -> String
getName f = concat [ moduleName f
                   , "_"
                   , datatypeName f
                   ]
```

Although you also need to enable the `KindSignatures` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the type signature for `getName`.

Running your code in a ghci session yields this:

```
ghci> :t getName
getName :: Datatype d => t d f a -> [Char]

ghci> getName p
"Lib9_Person"

ghci> :t getName p
getName p :: [Char]
```

Note: My code resides in the module `Lib9` which explains the output for `getName p`.

If you want to give it a type signature, enable `KindSignatures` and use:

```
getName :: Datatype d => (t :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *) d f a -> [Char]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what does the error message mean? Why can't i use "Rep a" but "Rep Person"?

Comment: The complete error message gives this clue: `NB: ‘Rep’ is a type function, and may not be injective`